# Subdomain in a new conf or in the current?

Tags: apache

Im trying to setup https://stats.example.com, but I'm wondering if I should create a new stats.example.com.conf or if i can somehow add `stats` as a subdomain directly into `sites-available/example.com.conf`?

Currently my example.com.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAdmin no-reply@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/example>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The thing is that I'm planning to use `/var/www/stats` for multiple sites on the same host. And i figure it would be easier and cleaner to add the subdomain into each specific conf, instead of having multipel domain confs and subdomain confs.

So instead of having

- `example.com.conf`
- `stats.example.com.conf`
- `example2.com.conf`
- `stats.example2.com.conf`

I just have

- `example.com.conf`
- `example2.com.conf`

## My question:

**Do I add the subdomain to the current config? Or do i make a new conf?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutly nothing that would prevent you from putting them all in the same conf.
On the other side, there is absolutly nothing that would prevent you from putting them all in different conf either.

So do it like you want :)

(if you have alot of different subdomains, I would put them in different confs, so its easier to find them later. If you have a ton of different domains and only a few subdomains each, I would put every domain (together with subdomains) in the same conf. But that is my personal opinion)

Comment: Thanks! Good point. Ended up with separate. made ssl much easier